# how to query get max id from varchar type?

Tags: php, mysql, max

i have table and column varchar type column id
and values are m1, m2, ... , m9,m10,m11,m12
then i use query

> select MAX(id) from table

but the result as m9 because it consider m10 as 'm','1','0' as an individual characters.so m9>m1(0).

Please help ?how to query get max id from varchar type ?

Comment: Your definition of strings comparison is certainly different from one MySQL (and most of other languages/platforms) uses. Try to define your comparison algorithm first (that is, given two strings, how to determine which of them is greater in your sense). We cannot say anything until it is defined; and chances are that, trying to define it, you'll understand that your sense is inconsistent and that strings set can not be ordered according to your sense e.g. because of the violation of transitivity.

Comment: If all ids are of the `m1234567` type, why don't you remove the `m` and convert the column to `INT`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select max(CAST((substring(id,2)) AS DECIMAL(5,2))) from table;
```

should do the trick.

Comment: sorry that should be DECIMAL(5,0)

Comment: how about get max id if value 1,2,3...,10,11,12 with varchar type ?

Comment: The max function works on numeric values, hence the need for a cast to decimal.  There isn't a numeric ordering available on alphanumeric values (i.e, values that contain letters AND numbers and which are stored as strings).  If things get too complicated, I suggest you do the ordering in your application code rather than in the query.

Answer (score 2):

You can use substring to achieve the max number

```
select max(CAST((substring(id,2)) AS DECIMAL(5,0))) from table
```

at the end you can also cancat with with 'm'

```
select concat('m'+ max(CAST((substring(id,2)) AS DECIMAL(5,0)))) from table
```